# Javascript and Jquery callstack

Tags: javascript, jquery, callstack

I see the callstack in Google Chrome. One row of it is this:

```
my.initAutocomplete.&.autocomplete.focus
```

How to call this method via code in JavaScript/Jquery - how to write the code that will call the same method as the row above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my.initAutocomplete['&'].autocomplete.focus`

But are you sure, there were dots on the sides of `&`?